# Is there a way to make this more concise and less repetitive? Or, is hard-coding the best option here?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, contains

```
df.loc[df['Campaign'].str.contains('Bathroom'), 'Product'] = 'Bathroom'
df.loc[df['Campaign'].str.contains('Roof'), 'Product'] = 'Roofing'
df.loc[df['Campaign'].str.contains('Siding'), 'Product'] = 'Siding'
df.loc[df['Campaign'].str.contains('Window'), 'Product'] = 'Window'
df.loc[df['Campaign'].str.contains('Water Treatment'), 'Product'] = 'Water Treatment'
df.loc[df['Campaign'].str.contains('Water Heater'), 'Product'] = 'Water Heater'
df.loc[df['Campaign'].str.contains('Pump'), 'Product'] = 'Pump'
df.loc[df['Campaign'].str.contains('Granulator'), 'Product'] = 'Granulator'
df.loc[df['Campaign'].str.contains('Plumbing'), 'Product'] = 'Plumbing'
df.loc[df['Campaign'].str.contains('Door'), 'Product'] = 'Door'
```

I feel going through and checking one by one like this is unprofessional. Any other ways recommended?

Comment: You could use a dictionary or a list of the words you want to check for. But I don't think there's anything inherently wrong with your code. Clear, readable code is always better than a hard to understand one-liner.

Comment: IMO in this case, the boilerplate hides the "core" of what's different in each case, making it harder to read.

Comment: @nordmanden I was thinking that! Thank you for the input

Answer (score 2):

Use a `list`:

```py
items = ['Bathroom', 'Roofing', 'Siding']  # etc, etc

for item in items:
    df.loc[df['Campaign'].str.contains(item), 'Product'] = item
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it really concise (and prevent looping through your entire DataFrame for each item) you could use the [`Series.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace) function as well.

```
items = ['Bathroom', 'Roofing', 'Siding']  # etc, etc
df.loc[:, 'Product'] = df['Campaign'].str.replace(fr'.*({items.join(|)}).*', lambda match: match.group(0), regex=True)
```

I did not have an example to test this though ;)

This uses a regex match to check whether any item is in your string and replaces the `'Product'` by the match if it is.